# "Er träumt" vs "Er träumet"

Tags: meaning, conjugation

Am Ende des berühmten Gedichtes Paul Celans, "Todesfuge", findet man die Verbalform "er träumet". Der Vers sagt:

> "er spielt mit den Schlangen und **träumet** der Tod ist ein Meister aus Deutschland".

Wie lässt sich denn diese Verbalendung verstehen? Sollte es da nicht "**er träumt**" stehen? Ich bin mir nicht sicher, was das heißen soll. Handelt es sich hier vielleicht um eine alte Konjugation, oder oder gibt's wohl eine ganz andere Erklärung dafür?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*er träumet* ist einfach eine alte Form der Konjugation. 
Die **Konjugation war früher** (ich hab keine Quelle bis wann genau, aber maximal bis Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts):

*ich träume*

*du träumest*

*er träumet*

*sie träumen*

*wir träumen*

*ihr träumet*

Das betrifft nicht nur das Verb *träumen* sondern alle Verben.

Es gibt im Deutschen sprachgeschichtlich eine Tendenz zur Nebensilben- bzw. Endsilbenabschwächung, die dazu führt, das unbetonte Silben, vor allem aber auch Endsilben über die Zeit hinweg schwächer und kürzer werden.
Das hat zur Folge, dass **heute die Konjugation in der Schriftsprache** ist:

*ich träume*

*du träumst*

*er träumt*

*sie träumen*

*wir träumen*

*ihr träumt*

Es wurde also die letzte Silbe bei den auf *t* endenden Formen reduziert, sodass die Formen statt zwei nur nur eine Silbe haben. Entsprechend werden die alten Formen oft in Gedichten verwendet werden, damit das Reimschema aufgeht.

Der Trend der Abschwächung hält übrigens an, wie du an der gesprochenen Sprache beobachten kannst. Denn die **gesprochene Konjugation** ist (bei den meisten Deutschen):

*ich träum*

*du träumst*

*er träumt*

*sie träumn*

*wir träumn*

*ihr träumt*

Hier verschwindet das Schwa der Endsilben auch bei den auf *n* endenden Formen. Es ist eine Frage der Zeit, bis sich diese Formen auch in der Schriftsprache niederschlagen ;-)

Comment: Ich denke, im Süden dürfte fast »wir/sie träume« (*drama* auf Bairisch, *träuma* bei schwäbischem Hochdeutsch) üblicher sein.

Comment: @Jan. Schwäbisch: mir träumet, ihr träumet, sie/Sie träumet.

Answer (score 5):

"Er träumet" ist heutzutage keine gültige Verbform von "träumen" mehr. Ich glaube, selbst zur Entstehung der "Todesfuge" war das schon ungebräuchlich.

Zu verstehen ist das in diesem Zusammenhang einfach wie "er träumt".

Meiner Meinung nach ist das, genau wie z.B. die heute ungebräuchliche Form "kommet" aus "Ihr Kinderlein kommet", ein Beispiel für eine gewisse dichterische Freiheit - die veraltete Form passt hier besser ins Versmaß.

Comment: Laut Duden ist es Konjunktiv I, Plural: _ihr träumet_ (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/traeumen). Aber ich stimme zu, daß es das Versmaß ist, weswegen diese Form gewählt wurde.

Comment: Huch, noch einer. Jetz samma scho mindestens drei Jans.

Answer (score 1):

Meines Wissens gibt es in keiner Zeitform jene Konjugation (der dritten Persion Singular), des Wort *träumens*.

Ob es sich dabei um eine ältere Form der Konjugierung handelt, kann ich nicht mit sicherheit ausschliessen, habe jedoch keine Beweise dafür und wüsste auch nicht davon.

Diese Art der Verbalendung habe ich jedoch schon in mehrern Gedichten gesehen, daher ist zu vermuten, dass es sich um eine spezielle Form, als eine *kleine Anpassung* der Gramatik in Gedichten erweist (es werden oft die Grenzen der Rechtschreibung etwas gedehnt bei Gedichten, Liedern, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Er träumet ist ähnlich wie er buk (für backen) ein Opfer der Zeit geworden, in der eine Sprache ständiger Anpassungen unterlegen ist, in der Wörter verschwinden und neue kommen.